# What does 'on the gimp' mean?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> There weren't a lot of opportunities
>   for retired car thieves **on the gimp**.

*(from the movie Gone in 60 Seconds)*

I'm at a loss as to what it means. The word 'gimp' has many interesting meanings but none of them seem to fit the context. So, I figured, that must be some sort of an idiom. Alas, I couldn't find it either (even in the Urban Dictionary). What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Gimp* is a slur for someone with a disability or physical deformity. It has also come to mean someone incapable or incompetent. The *ADHS* finds usages dating from the 1920s, many of them referring to someone with a bad leg who therefore limps. However, there is an earlier (1877) adjectival usage meaning inferior, second-rate.

The expression *on the gimp* seems unique to *Gone in 60 seconds*, where it appears here as well:

> MEMPHIS: You know where the others are?
>
> Donny frowns... Looks closely at Memphis ... Then:
>
> DONNY ASTRICKY: Most of 'em are gone. The Dyar Boys are doing a nickel at Chino; Henry Santoro and Frankie Fish are moving  weight in Florida; Bill Doolin was killed in Denver... Atley Jackson's **on the gimp** and runnin' errands for Calitri;

So "on the gimp" refers to retired car thieves who no longer have the skills to boost cars and one Atley Jackson who apparently was once a car thief and is now reduced to the status of errand boy.

I think it's fair to infer from its usage in the film and as documented elsewhere that it means someone who's lost his skills and cannot be considered competent.